# Gracenote GNSDK is not retrieving genre on Android

Tags: android, gracenote

I'm studiyng gracenote gnsdk in an android application. With the developer key I have, I can retrieve basic information about the music, but I can't retrieve info such as mood and genre.

Does anyone knows a way to get this information? I'm following the example, like this:

```
String genre = gnAlbum.trackMatched().genre(GnDataLevel.kDataLevel_1);
if(genre == null || genre.isEmpty()){
    genre = gnAlbum.genre(GnDataLevel.kDataLevel_1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the docs you have to load a locale object to get genre results, e.g.

```
mGnLocale = new GnLocale(GnLocaleGroup.kLocaleGroupMusic, GnLanguage.kLanguageEnglish, GnRegion.kRegionGlobal, GnDescriptor.kDescriptorDefault, mGnUser);
mGnLocale.setGroupDefault();
```

this takes quite a while so you might want to run that in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks @AndyJ. I was missing that part of the doc. After setting the locale, it's everything working fine.