# Gracenote (GNSDK for mobile) missing artist's name

Tags: android, gracenote

i'm using *Gracenote* (GNSDK for mobile) to identify songs through smartphone microphones.

So far it is working well, but most of the times the results don't contain the artist's name.

Only sometimes the name is present in `track().artist().name().display()`.

Does *Gracenote* not have that information? Am i not allowed to access it?

Comment: Yes. Gracenote has this information. If you are able to ID a song this information should be available.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your response. I guessed it should be included (and sometimes is) but more than half of the time it's not. Setting a locale like described there
 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030365/gracenote-gnsdk-is-not-retrieving-genre-on-android?rq=1) didn't help either

Comment: Could you post a GNID of the song(s) that is missing the artist name? I could at least verify that if the data exists or not.

Comment: Hi @Alan. Thanks for getting back to me. I had put the issue on pause for a while and just figured it out. I had to use the album.artist().name().display() instead of track().artist().name().display()

since you're already may i impose another question? ;) Is there a way to get spotify-id as a community user? i only get deezer-track-id (several of them actually)

Comment: You should contact Gracenote if you need to access additional external IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a while.

I had to use the `album.artist().name().display()` instead of `track().artist().name().display()`.

It seems the track-artist's name is only present if it differs from the album artist's name.